# Link de acesso a páginas

Tags: php, link, redirect

Como faço pra quando clicar no link exemplo produtos, mudar somente exemplo conteudo e deixar header e footer quetos? fazer com Slin e Rain frameworks, HELP!!!.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar PHP para isso:

Por exemplo

```
<section class="section">
  <div class="container">
  <?php
  $url = (isset($_GET['url'])) ? $_GET['url'] : 'login';
  $url = array_filter(explode('/', $url));

  $file = './pages/' . $url[0] . '.php';

  if (is_file($file)) {
    require_once $file;
  } else {
    require_once './pages/404.php';
  }
  ?>
  </div>
</section>
```

Onde você vai precisar também de um `htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA]
```

O que esse código basicamente faz é chamar o arquivo `php` dentro da pasta pages indicado na `url`: `exemplo.com/contatos` sem `.php` no final se a página existir ela é incluída se não ela retorna a página `404.php`

Answer (score 0):

Você pode carregar dinamicamente as propriedades do produto por meio de ajax ou usar um framework front-end.
O caminho mais fácil é carregar os dados dinamicamente por ajax, pois você não aprende da noite pro dia um framework, e se usa de má forma o prejudicado é você em pouco tempo.